# setZoom acting peculiar when passing a javascript variable

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create links in separate pages to a map.  When a user clicks a link it will redirect to the map and display the geologic polygon corresponding to the link.  However, after hours of debugging I've discovered that the setZoom function is preventing me from doing this and I can't figure out why.  If you click the button 'See Tg on a map' at http://www.geology.ar.gov/test/javascript_variablePassing1.html it creates the url 'http://www.geology.ar.gov/geology/strat_geomap.htm?formation=tg'.  When the map page loads it parses out the 'tg' and passes it to functions showStratChart(tg) and processGeoFm(tg).  But in the function processGeoFm() it uses the setZoom function and the map view hops to another location.  Currently I've commented processGeoFm() for testing...

```
 var lblTextPass = new String(window.location);
var equalIndex = lblTextPass.indexOf("=") + 1;
//window.alert(theleft);
if (equalIndex > 0) {
    //var delay = 2000;
    //setTimeout(function(){
        var fmLabel = lblTextPass.substring(equalIndex, lblTextPass.length);
//      //window.alert(fmLabel);
        //processGeoFm(fmLabel);
        showStratChart(fmLabel);
        map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(36.027791, -91.188240));

        //if (map.getZoom()) {
            map.setZoom(9); 
        //}


     //},delay);

} else {
    processGeoFm("Ozarks");

}
```

If I comment out map.setZoom(9) the map won't hop to another lat/lng.  If you go directly to the map http://www.geology.ar.gov/geology/strat_geomap.htm the map calls processGeoFm("Ozarks") and it doesn't cause the map view to hop nor does it happen when you call processGeoFm() when selecting something, such as Gravel (tg), from the drop-down menus above the map.  I really could use some help on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another stack overflow question led me to this resolution, which I had to add to my processGeoFm function....

```
 var zmListener = google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, "idle", function() {
            //this corrects bug with setZoom function when passing a variable from another page
            map.setZoom(7);

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(34.75, -91.184)); //this ensures correct lat/lng
        }); 

    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(34.75, -91.184));
```

Not sure why I had to do this however